# What's preventing np.random.shuffle from reshuffling my array?

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle

When I shuffle this array, it seems to remain unchanged. What am I missing? I'm trying to make a (6,4) array of random zeros and 255s:

```
import numpy as np
clr_values = [0,255]
ifslst = clr_values * 12
img_flat_sorted = np.array(ifslst)
img_2d_sorted = img_flat_sorted.reshape((6,4))
np.random.shuffle(img_2d_sorted)
```

seems to leave img_2d_sorted unchanged. I was expecting it to be shuffled. Before is the same as After. What went wrong?

```
array([[  0, 255,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255,   0, 255]])
```

Comment: `np.random.choice([0,255],size=(6,4))`?

Answer (score 4):

It *is* being shuffled, but every row being the same, it *looks* unchanged. Note that arrays are only shuffled in the first dimension; i.e. in a 2D array, its rows are moved around, but the contents of each row are left as-is. Since each of your rows is `[0, 255, 0, 255]`, if they changed locations you could never tell.

If you want to have the same number of `0` and `255`, but at random positions, consider shuffling the 1D array, before `reshape`.

```
clr_values = [0,255]
ifslst = clr_values * 12
img_flat = np.array(ifslst)
np.random.shuffle(img_flat)
img_flat.reshape((6, 4))
# => array([[  0,   0, 255,   0],
#           [  0,   0, 255,   0],
#           [255, 255, 255, 255],
#           [  0, 255, 255, 255],
#           [255,   0, 255,   0],
#           [  0, 255,   0,   0]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a basic, unmodded function to shuffle all the values in a 2D array:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import shuffle
def Shuffle2D(lst):
  for i in range(0, len(lst):
    lst[i] = shuffle(lst[i])
  return shuffle(lst)
```

This simple function simply shuffles all the values in each 'row' of a 2D array. It then preforms an additional shuffle of the whole array. This should work for shuffling an images pixels. Note that this function doesn't create an array of 255's and 0's, but your code for that looks correct.

Comment: 1) Where did `lst` come from? 2) `np.random.shuffle()` changes the input in-place and returns `None` instead of changed result.

Comment: @MechanicPig fixed it. sorry about that